# Why is this question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67030/movie-where-a-man-runs-with-a-cam-in-his-hand) was asked and answered on Jan 17th 2017. However it was marked as a duplicate of a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72006/action-movie-which-shows-the-story-of-a-terrorist-attack-on-the-us-president-fro) which was asked on Apr 20th 2017. How is this possible when the description of marked as duplicate is **This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.** Shouldn't there be an automatic check which prevents this kind of marking as duplicate?

Comment: It's not a bug. It is an automated statement. One with better answer remains original and all other questions irrelevant of date and time becomes duplicate. It depends on quality of questions and answers. Moreover the question which is marked as a duplicate in present case has an accepted answer. Automatic check is not required. It depends on quality of questions asked. The later question has better description than the earlier one.

Comment: In that case isn't the wording "This question has been asked before" wrong?

Comment: Yeah. It is.You know this statement is not exclusive for this site alone.It is a standard one for all SE sites.  IMO the tags [tag:bug] and [tag:support] are not relevant for this question. [Feature-request] would be apt. Also edit the question and title accordingly to fit the [tag:feature-request]. All the best.

Comment: I have a question about this. Yes both question have the same answer but their descriptions are not similar at all, so, are they really duplicates?